# Get custom attributes of a product for confirmation email in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, email

I need to add a `warehouse_location` custom attribute for each product in order and shipment confirmation emails. In order to do so I modified two templates: `default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` and `default/template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml`. Both Templates contain identical code:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->load($_item->getProductId());
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_coll = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_coll as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getData('warehouse_location');
    }
} else {
    echo $_product->getWarehouseLocation();
}
```

It does not work. If the check for product type is removed and I just do this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $_product->getWarehouseLocation();
```

Then it obviously works only for simple products.

Any suggestions why this doesn't work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. If anyone has a similar problem you need to assign the load to a variable:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$p = $_product->load($_item->getProductId());
if($p->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($p);
    $simple_coll = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_coll as $simple_product){
        echo $simple_product->getData('warehouse_location');
    }
} else {
    echo $p->getWarehouseLocation();
}
```

I have no idea what causes this behaviour since it worked fine without the check for `PRODUCT_TYPE`

Answer (score 1):

A better way is not to load the product by the item ID, but simply getting the product via the item:

```
$customAttribute = $_item->getProduct()->getCustomAttribute();
```

or

```
$customAttributeText = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('custom_attribute');
```

And using that